# Fill missing data and transform rows to column in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this,

```
df_nba = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['name', np.nan,np.nan,'course','eca','pages',
                                 'name', np.nan,np.nan,'course','pages',
                                 'name', np.nan,np.nan,'course','eca','pages',
                                 'name', np.nan,np.nan,'course','eca','pages',
                                 'name', np.nan,np.nan,'course','pages',
                                 'name', np.nan,np.nan,'course','eca','pages',

                               ], 
                        'col2': ['jim', 'California','M','Biology','Biology Club',1,
                                 'jim', 'California','M','Physics',2,
                                 'greg', 'Arizona','M','Geography','Jazz Band',3,
                                 'greg', 'Arizona','M','Physics','Photography',4,
                                 'jesse', 'Washington','F','Economics',5,
                                 'jesse', 'Washington','F','Literature','Photography',6,
       
                     ]})

col1    col2
0   name    jim
1   NaN California
2   NaN M
3   course  Biology
4   eca Biology Club
5   pages   1
6   name    jim
7   NaN California
8   NaN M
9   course  Physics
10  pages   2
11  name    greg
12  NaN Arizona
13  NaN M
14  course  Geography
15  eca Jazz Band
16  pages   3
17  name    greg
18  NaN Arizona
19  NaN M
20  course  Physics
21  eca Photography
22  pages   4
23  name    jesse
24  NaN Washington
25  NaN F
26  course  Economics
27  pages   5
28  name    jesse
29  NaN Washington
30  NaN F
31  course  Literature
32  eca Photography
33  pages   6
```

There are two consecutive rows always missing after the row `name` for each person. Can I fill the data with `States` and `Gender` first then I can transpose the data to a column wise view?

The output will be like,

```
        name      states     gender   course           eca           pages
                                      
0       jim      California    M       Biology       Biology Club     1
1       jim      California    M       Physics       NaN              2
2       greg     Arizona       M       Geography     Jazz Band        3
3       greg     Arizona       M       Physics       Photography      4
4      jesse     Washington    F       Economics     NaN              5
5      jesse     Washington    F       Literature    Photography      6
```

Comment: There is always two fields missing after each name? No other variations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mask where the value "name" is in col1 and `shift` to fill the right values in col1. Then reshape the result with `unstack`, after `set_index` with a `cumsum` on the mask, incremental value every "name" in col1 and col1 itself.

```
#get a mask where name in col1
mask = df_nba['col1'].eq('name')

# fill the two following nan with the rigth value
df_nba.loc[mask.shift(1,fill_value=False), 'col1'] = 'states'
df_nba.loc[mask.shift(2,fill_value=False), 'col1'] = 'gender'

#reshape
df_ = (df_nba.set_index([mask.cumsum(),
                         df_nba['col1'].to_numpy()])
             ['col2'].unstack()
             .rename_axis(None) #cosmetic
             [['name','states','gender','course','eca','pages']] #reorder the columns
      )

print(df_)
    name      states gender      course           eca pages
1    jim  California      M     Biology  Biology Club     1
2    jim  California      M     Physics           NaN     2
3   greg     Arizona      M   Geography     Jazz Band     3
4   greg     Arizona      M     Physics   Photography     4
5  jesse  Washington      F   Economics           NaN     5
6  jesse  Washington      F  Literature   Photography     6
```

Comment: Alternatively you can `pivot` by `df_nba.assign(group=mask.cumsum()).pivot("group", "col1", "col2")` for the reshape part.

Comment: Hi @HenryYik and Ben. Thanks for the answers! Do you know how to avoid duplicates when set the pivot method? I re-run both of your solution it gives me an error `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`, It seems when I group up the values it didn't consider the index from `pages`. Ben's solution works well on this test dataset. But it showed me the same error on my file about the duplicates when reshaping the dataframe.

Comment: Thank you so much! I final found why it didn't work... There are some rows in my file that missing the `name` that made the `unstack` function not work. Thanks again the code is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

It is not an efficient solution but it can do what you want.
if you provide col1 & col2 as lists

```py
# to fill missing values in col1
for i in range(1,len(col1)):
    if(col1[i-1] == "name"):
       col1[i] = "states"
    if(col1[i-1] == "states"):
       col1[i] = "gender"

# to create list of dictionaries for each record
data=[]
temp={}
for i in range(len(c1)):
    temp[col1[i]]=col2[i]
    if(col1[i]=="pages"):
        data.append(temp)
        temp={}

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
name_index = df_nba.loc[df_nba['col1']=='name'].index
for i in name_index:
    df_nba.loc[i+1:i+2, 'col1'] = ['states', 'gender']
```

Now to get the transposed table:

```
pivot = df_nba.pivot(columns = 'col1')
pivot_nba = pd.DataFrame()
for col in pivot['col2']:
    pivot_nba[col] = pivot['col2'][col].dropna().reset_index(drop = True)
pivot_nba

    course        eca               gender  name    pages   states
0   Biology       Biology Club      M       jim     1       California
1   Physics       Jazz Band         M       jim     2       California
2   Geography     Photography       M       greg    3       Arizona
3   Physics       Photography       M       greg    4       Arizona
4   Economics     NaN               F       jesse   5       Washington
5   Literature    NaN               F       jesse   6       Washington
```